# module face_recognition saving live webcam to TXT file

Tags: python, face-recognition

Anyone could help me figure out how to save faces that were detected in **LIVE** webcam to a text file, like if it saw my name it would save it into a text file with my name in it, 
Example:

It detects my face --

NAME was saved into a text file

Thanks, module is python3 module face_recognition

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide your previous attempts to solve your problem, eg. you could paste code fragments etc.

Comment: I haven't tried nothing as i didn't know what to do, any way to make it save what it saw on the webcam into a text file?

Comment: @MarkSchäfer help, or anyone else?

Comment: In this case, this question is out of scope for StackOverflow, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
I suggest to read the respective documentation, to google for tutorials and the like and to attempt your own solution. When you got specific problems, you can post them here.

Comment: @MarkSchäfer ive went through every tutorial couldnt find one ive been searching for 5 hours and gave up

Comment: writing in file should be in any Python tutorial for beginners. It is so basic knowledge that you may not find it in tutorials for face recognitions which are not for Python's beginners. `open()`, `write()`, `close()`